# Force foreach to use const iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers

I have a custom container class which implements `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions. Then I use it in a foreach loop, but it seems to require `begin()` and `end()` member functions, even though I tried using `const` modifier:

```
for (const auto val: container)
```

and like this:

```
for (auto const val: container)
```

and like this:

```
for (const auto const val: container)
```

Is it possible to force foreach to use constant c-functions?

Comment: No, it only uses `begin` and `end`. Just make `begin` and `end` functions that return a `const_iterator` if operating on a const object.

Comment: @chris but what if we want to `const`ly iterate over a mutable object? Do we have to do a cast?

Comment: @uk4321, I believe the same problem exists with the standard containers.

Comment: You know `it` in your code is not actually an iterator but an instance of the type the iterator contains? You probably want to say `for (const auto& inst : container)`

Comment: @kfsone Yes, that's true. Thank you, I've updated the code. But in my case it's just an integer.

Answer (score 10):

Sure: make the range appear as if it is a `const` range:

```
template <typename T>
T const& make_const(T const& argument) {
    return argument;
}

// ...
for (auto&& value: make_const(argument)) {
    ...
}
```

In all cases the range-based `for` will, however, use `begin()` and `end()` and never `cbegin()` or `cend()`. You might want to provide these instead:

```
template <typename T>
auto begin(my_container<T> const& t) -> decltype(t.cbegin()) {
    return t.cbegin();
}
template <typename T>
auto end(my_container<T> const& t) -> decltype(t.cend()) {
    return t.cend();
}
```

Obviously, you want to replace `my_container` by a suitable container type. Personally, I would probably just provide suitable `begin()` and `end()` members.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what the decision to provide only `cbegin()` and `cend()` is, but those are not used in the range based for. If you want to use your container in a range based for you *need* to provide `begin()` and `end()` (although you can have them return const iterators)

Comment: The reason was to limit container mutations to a few functions.

Comment: @Max, you can provide `const_iterator begin() const` for that, in the same way that `std::set` does

Comment: I understand that. It just seems strange that STL uses c-prefixed functions to make the constness explicit and foreach can only work with implicit constness.

Comment: @Max: `cbegin` and `cend` are new to C++11, all containers pre-C++11 only had `begin` and `end`, and there are usually two overloads of each, for const and non-const objects. The strange case is a container that does not offer `begin` or `end` but does offer `cbegin` and `cend`. There is no need to support range based for using `cbegin` and `cend` when all (but your) containers share the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

You should always provide `begin()`/`end()` functions in *two* overloads, a const and a non-const one. The purpose of the new `cbegin()`/`cend()` functions is to allow deduction with `auto`, as in:

```
for (auto it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); ) { /* ... */ }
```

Without the new functions, you could only get the non-const iterator here (or insert a very awkward cast).

Comment: ty - providing two overloads worked great for me - I was banging my head of the wall for the last hour trying to figure out why range-based-for would not use cbegin()/cend().